# What are the possible reasons I am not getting cold air from my air conditioner?

Tags: hvac

my heat pump outside is working but my central air conditioning/heating unit in the garage makes a hissing sound or faint sound of water running. There is air coming from the vents. The very last time I used the heat, about a month ago the same thing happened but when I switched to air conditioning the last month, it worked until now. What are the possible problems?

Comment: It would be nice to know whether the diagnosis was capacitor,  coolant,  or if you just decided to replace it without resolving the cause.

Answer (score 1):

If all is well with your outside unit, I would double-check your AC coil in the main unit indoors. It could be frozen over and thus not cooling the air. This same exact thing happened to us about 3 weeks ago. We moved into a "new" house (new to us anyways, haha) and not many things were being taken care of well... in simple terms, a freeze-over like this can happen because the coil drain is clogged with dust particles and/or sludge. This means there's no where for the condensate to go and leads to a frozen coil. Hopes this experience can help someone avoid a big maintenance bill in the future!
To fix the issue, use a hair dryer or heat gun to melt the ice away. DO NOT CHIP AWAY at the ice since the coils are very delicate and you could puncture one easily.

Comment: Frozen lines are usually due to a lack of coolant in the system.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are low on refrigerant or you have a failed compressor. This is not something you can fix yourself. Call for service.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an easy fix. Go look in your air conditioner, there will be a capacitor which is cylindrical shaped.  If it is puffed out or distorted in shape, it needs to be replaced. You can replace this yourself. My suggestion is to first take a picture of how the wires are connected and it's simply plug and play. Take the old capacitor to the supply house so you get the right replacement.

Comment: Want to add the obligatory warning that power should be secured before going into the unit.  Capacitors can maintain a charge even with the power off,  please be careful and measure both power applied and power remaining when playing with the cap!